# using single canvas i have drawn two different diagrams using javascript,is there any way i can remove last drawn diagram in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

using single canvas element i have drawn two different diagrams using javascript,is there any way i could remove last drawn diagram in canvas.here is my canvas code `<canvas style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;" id="cns"></canvas>` and i have created my diagram using javascript and in button click i am trying to remove last drawn diagram `var c = document.getElementById("cns");
    var d = c.getContext("2d");
    d.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    d.fillRect(0, 0, 106, 106);
    var c1 = document.getElementById("cns");
    var d1= c.getContext("2d");
    d1.fillStyle = "#00A550";
    d1.fillRect(0, 0, 90, 90);
    $("#clk").click(function () {
        d1.clearRect(0, 0, 90, 90);
    });`,but it clears the whole rectangle on given size.is there any i could clear last drawn image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're getting multiple references to the same canvas (id=cns) and multiple references to its context.

For any single canvas, there is 1-and-only-1 context for that canvas.  A single canvas does not have multiple layers (like Photoshop does for example).

Therefore your `d` and `d1` variables actually contain the same context. And that's why clearing either `d` or `d1` will clear the same area on the canvas.

The usual method for handling multiple sets of drawings (multiple diagrams) on canvas is to:

- save enough information to recreate each individual drawing (diagram) -- usually saved in a JS object.
- clear the entire canvas.
- use the saved information to redraw the currently desired diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `context.save()` method to save to canvas before  inserting the second diagram. Then when you want to remove this second diagram use `context.restore()` and it should do the trick.

Comment: i want restore the save in button click but i cant do it ,it still remains the same

Comment: @Kheldar.  `context.save` does not save the drawings on the canvas--it saves the context state (fillStyle, strokeStyle, lineWidth, transforms, etc). ;-)